# Inserting sql query into temp table for later use

Tags: sql, database, oracle, toad, temp

I have a table which I need to perform actions on and then insert the result in a temp table so I can join the temp table with other tables later.  Here's my code:

```
if object_id ('tempdb..tempMHR_X') is not null
drop table tempMHR_X;

create table tempMHR_X (
tempTM_LINE_ITEM_SA_ID int,
tempMH_X int,
tempCHRG_DT_MONTH int,
tempCHRG_DT_YEAR int
)

insert into tempMHR_X (tempTM_LINE_ITEM_SA_ID, tempMH_X, tempCHRG_DT_MONTH, tempCHRG_DT_YEAR)
select tc.TM_LINE_ITEM_SA_ID, sum(tc.MH_X), extract(month from tc.CHRG_DT), extract(year from tc.CHRG_DT)
from TM_CHARGE tc
group by tc.TM_LINE_ITEM_SA_ID, extract(month from tc.CHRG_DT), extract(year from tc.CHRG_DT)
```

I am getting an 'ORA-00922: Missing or invalid operation' error on the insert statement.  I have tested everything from the beginning of the select statement down and it returned the correct result.  Now, I just want get that result into the temp table tempMH_X so I can join the temp table with other tables.

FYI, I am using an Oracle 10g database.  I have tried using the '#' sign before my temp table name, but TOAD says that is an invalid operator.  Any help is much appreciated.  Thank you!

James

Comment: If your select query is working, change it so that it is selecting only one field.  Try to insert that field into your temp table.  If you succeed, add a second field.  Keep going until you find the error or finish the job.

Comment: Are you missing a semicolon after your create table statement?

Comment: Yup, was missing the semicolon.  Thanks all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing semicolon after CREATE TABLE?